# What are the differences between XeLaTeX and pdfLaTeX?

Tags: latex, pdflatex, xetex

There are multiple TeX typesetting engines. Both commands (`pdflatex` and `xelatex`) generate a PDF.  What is the technical/effective/historical/etc. difference between these two commands?  I'm using TeX Live.

Comment: Related: [Frequently loaded packages: Differences between pdfLaTeX and XeLaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2984/5764)

Comment: Duplicate: [The differences between TeX engines](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13593/5764)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[PdfTeX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PdfTeX) and [XeTeX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XeTeX) and the equivalent commands for `latex` are two implementations for the same purpose, as you have pointed out already. The Wikipedia articles have more details on the history and development.

One of the main differences from an operational point of view is that XeTeX has better support for fonts -- in particular you can use system fonts instead of only TeX fonts. It also has better support for non-latin character encodings.

Comment: And UTF8 (so no `babel` nightmares), plus including nearly any of the common graphics formats w/o the need of any prior conversion.

Comment: So, `xelatex` can be used on the same files that `pdflatex` can render?

Comment: As far as I know yes.

Comment: I have found at least [one example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/552423/102826) where a valid `pdflatex` file does not work in xelatex. I have a different issue right now, but couldn't pinpoint it yet - it also works with pdflatex but not xelatex.

Comment: One of the exceptions I've found since is the `pdfinfo` command that only works in pdflatex.

Comment: pdfinfo has nothing to do with TeX. It's a utility to get info from PDF files, however produced

Comment: I mean the `\pdfinfo{}` TeX command.